# Importing *cell-formatting* information from excel file into R

Tags: r, xls, xlsx

I have been given excel files (`.xlsx`) where the format of the cell is relevant information which I need to capture.  The key formatting of interest are (1) cell color and (2) border (left + right, full box or absent).

Is it possible to read this into R?

Comment: Try `getCellStyle` in the **XLConnect** package.

Comment: Thanks @Joran, I didn't realize it was called style and not format.  I'll give that a look.

Comment: You should educate whoever created these files on safer ways to record data ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very old question but still comes up in searches so I think it is useful to point people toward the `tidyxl` package.

`tidyxl::xlsx_cells()` reads an Excel spreadsheet in as a data frame where each row represents a single cell of the spreadsheet, with its address (e.g. `A1`), contents, and properties.

`tidyxl::xlsx_formats()` returns a nested list of all the different cell formats in the Excel spreadsheet.

The `local_format_id` column in the data frame returned by `xlsx_cells()` allows you to look up the formatting information for each cell in the list returned by `xlsx_formats()`.

More information is included in the [tidyxl package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyxl/vignettes/tidyxl.html).

Comment: can't believe this question remained unanswered for six years!

Comment: Well, the tidyxl package didn't exist until 2017 but nowadays I think it's the easiest way to deal with Excel cell formatting in R, although unfortunately it only supports .xlsx and not .xls

Comment: Unfortunately it's still only half the solution. Tidyxl will read the data and allow it to be stored and reproduced via dput/rda, but nothing that writes excel workbooks will use that data. XLConnect and openxlsx will write excel workbooks, but have no way to "portably" store formatting information, you're stuck lugging around a .xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

I've been really happy with the Python openpyxl project. Perhaps you can manipulate (preprocess) the xlsx in python to be digestable by R (perhaps CSV or XLS).

http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#tutorial

http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook

There's an XLS import in Quick R:

http://www.statmethods.net/input/importingdata.html