# How to read cell formatting (indentation) information from Excel into R?

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to import a large number of Excel files into R. The irritating thing about it is that some *information is contained in whether or not the text in the cell is indented.* Below is an example (I apologize for having to use a screenshot), where the entries "Main" and "Secondary" are indented because they belong to the "Space heating" category in the row above. The indented rows have a left indent set to 1, while the non-indented rows have left indent set to 0.

[image: Excel screenshot]

I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816984/importing-cell-formatting-information-from-excel-file-into-r) that `getCellStyle` in the **XLConnect** package might be able to extract this information but it seems like that can only be used to retrieve named cell styles. Is it possible to extract this information within R even if there is no named style?

The Excel file in the screenshot (20 KB) can be found at https://www.eia.gov/consumption/residential/data/2015/hc/hc1.1.xlsx (Residential Energy Consumption Survey from the U.S. Energy Information Administration).

Comment: I'm afraid you may have to fix this directly in the file itself. You can partially automate this with the suggestion here: https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Discussions/Indented-excel-file-input/td-p/78851

Comment: An alternative is that if we know only "main" and "secondary" are ever used this way, you can search those out and either filter them out or mutate them to reflect their category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should have done this work before posting this question, but I found the amazing **tidyxl** package to solve this problem as follows. Hopefully it can help others.

```
library(tidyxl)
cells11 <- xlsx_cells('hc1.1.xlsx', sheets = 'data')
formats11 <- xlsx_formats('hc1.1.xlsx')

indented_cells <- which(formats11$local$alignment$indent > 0)
cells11[cells11$local_format_id %in% indented_cells, ]
```

This outputs a tibble with only the cells that are indented.

```
# A tibble: 11 x 21
   sheet address   row   col is_blank data_type error logical numeric date                character character_forma~ formula is_array formula_ref
   <chr> <chr>   <int> <int> <lgl>    <chr>     <chr> <lgl>     <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>     <list>           <chr>   <lgl>    <chr>      
 1 data  A15        15     1 FALSE    character NA    NA           NA NA                  Main      <tibble [1 x 14~ NA      FALSE    NA         
 2 data  A16        16     1 FALSE    character NA    NA           NA NA                  Secondary <tibble [1 x 14~ NA      FALSE    NA         
 3 data  A22        22     1 FALSE    character NA    NA           NA NA                  Main      <tibble [1 x 14~ NA      FALSE    NA         
 4 data  A23        23     1 FALSE    character NA    NA           NA NA                  Secondary <tibble [1 x 14~ NA      FALSE    NA         
 5 data  A29        29     1 FALSE    character NA    NA           NA NA                  Main      <tibble [1 x 14~ NA      FALSE    NA         
 6 data  A30        30     1 FALSE    character NA    NA           NA NA                  Secondary <tibble [1 x 14~ NA      FALSE    NA         
 7 data  A36        36     1 FALSE    character NA    NA           NA NA                  Main      <tibble [1 x 14~ NA      FALSE    NA         
 8 data  A37        37     1 FALSE    character NA    NA           NA NA                  Secondary <tibble [1 x 14~ NA      FALSE    NA         
 9 data  A41        41     1 FALSE    character NA    NA           NA NA                  Main      <tibble [1 x 14~ NA      FALSE    NA         
10 data  A42        42     1 FALSE    character NA    NA           NA NA                  Secondary <tibble [1 x 14~ NA      FALSE    NA         
11 data  A44        44     1 TRUE     blank     NA    NA           NA NA                  NA        <NULL>           NA      FALSE    NA         
# ... with 6 more variables: formula_group <int>, comment <chr>, height <dbl>, width <dbl>, style_format <chr>, local_format_id <int>
```